# CMYK image resize/shrink TIFF file/add registration marks

Tags: resize, cmyk, print-production, screen-printing, tiff

New to the forum and graphic design. I am a veteran screen printer.

I've recently gone into business for myself, and I am having the hardest time hiring freelance graphic designers. I've recently started to try and learn graphic design on my own.

I commissioned a piece for CMYK. The artist created the image and separated the colors. However, the company that prints my film is telling me that the PNG files have no set size and no registration marks.

He also tells me that the white file (the underbase) is set as a TIFF file and is enormous. Would anyone be willing to coach me on how to resize and or set sizes to these images?

The artist who did them has been paid and won't return my calls. I would hire someone to fix it, but all of the “freelance” artists I find have a bit of a language barrier and I can't convey what I need to someone who doesn't understand screen printing... or English for that matter.

Comment: I was going to answer this and realized any effective answer would be a small novel. The gist is, no one can "teach you" what you need to know on a message board. It's too broad. What you *need* to do is hire someone *that actually knows what they are doing* rather than anyone simply calling themselves a "freelancer". I realize it can be challenging to sort through many candidates, but if you explain this problem.. they should (rather easily) understand how to correct things, or possibly *redo* the work to proper specifications.

Comment: This is *basic* stuff for print work. Any local first year community college design student would probably understand what needs to be done. If you can't find English speaking freelancers, you are either paying too little or looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to get some print layout capable software which adds (if wanted) the common print markings. Ability to handle grayscale, CMYK and spot colors is a must if you plan to handle all kind of print works.

The most common solution is to use basic Adobe CC set (=Photoshop for photos and other raster images, Illustrator for vectors, InDesign for composing the printable pages, Acrobat for creating ready to print PDF files) That costs money, but also gives well respected tools. InDesign maybe is needless if you are not going to compose books, magazines nor other multipage stuff. Illustrator also has print preparing tools as well as Acrobat. You do not need to shell out say US$1000,- at a time because Adobe's software is only for rent.

There exists low cost altenatives. Serif Affinity series is one. Very capable freeware is also available such as Krita for raster images and Scribus for layout works. GIMP and Inkscape unfortunately handle only RGB images.